# Get type of object received over sockets

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I have a Client/Server application. I use a class called MessageHolder that takes an object which gets send. I have Companies, Contracts, Contacts, etc classes that can be send with this MessageHolder class. Now when my server receives the MessageHolder how can I get the type of the Object contained within it?

Message Holder Class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MessageHolder
{
    public object company { get; set; }
    public CompanyCreationClass(object Company)
    {
        company = Company;
    }
}
```

Comment: typeof(MessageHolderInstance); ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method:

```
System.Type t = company.GetType()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

I will suggest something.
You may find Generics a better alternative than passing "object" around.

```
public class MyGenericHolder<T>
{
    public MyGenericHolder()
    {
    }

    private T _theItem = default(T) ;

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        this._theItem = item;
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        return this._theItem;
    }
}




class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            MyGenericHolder<int> intHolder = new MyGenericHolder<int>();
            intHolder.Push(101);
            int x = intHolder.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            MyGenericHolder<string> stringHolder = new MyGenericHolder<string>();
            stringHolder.Push("Hello Generics");
            string y = stringHolder.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine(y);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work but, not sure how to use. because I have to do a if statement that check it to. `CompanyClass Company = new CompanyClass()`. But my New Company class takes parameters. This makes it difficult to create a new instance if I do not want to add parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageHolder obj = new  MessageHolder(); 
Type t = typeof(obj);

// Alternatively, you could use 
MessageHolder obj = new  MessageHolder(); 
Type t = obj.GetType();
```